# Getting Missing Qualification Error on row.``Petal Width`|]) Line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, algorithm, f#, k-means

Thank you in advance for any replies and the answers on this forum have been invaluable in my research. I am student learning F# for the purposes of a research project on language paradigms and am attempting to utilize a fabulous example from http://trelford.com/blog/post/specialk.aspx in order to play with a simple k-means algorithm. I am getting an error I am not sure how to fix and was hoping for some guidance. Much Obliged and Here is the code and error is: Getting Missing Qualification Error on row.`` `Petal Width ``|]) Line

//Code From http://trelford.com/blog/post/specialk.aspx

```
open System
open FSharp

type Iris = CsvProvider<irisDataFile>
let iris = Iris.Load(irisDataFile)
let irisData = iris.Data |> Seq.toArray
//
///// classifcations
let y = irisData |> Array.map (fun row -> row.Class)
/// feature vectors
let X = irisData |> Array.map (fun row -> 
  [|row.``Sepal Length`` 
    row.``Sepal Width`` 
    row.``Petal Length`` 
    row.``Petal Width`|])


//Computing k-means centroids:

let K = 3 // The Iris dataset is known to only have 3 clusters

let seed = 
  [|X.[0]; X.[1]; X.[2]|]  // pick bad centroids on purpose

let centroidResults = 
  KMeans.computeCentroids seed X |> Seq.take iterationLimit



(* K-Means Algorithm *)

/// Group all the vectors by the nearest center. 
let classify centroids vectors = 
  vectors |> Array.groupBy (fun v -> centroids |> Array.minBy (distance v))

/// Repeatedly classify the vectors, starting with the seed centroids
let computeCentroids seed vectors = 
  seed |> Seq.iterate (fun centers -> classify centers vectors |> Array.map (snd >> average))
```

Comment: Oh, Forgot to mention I am ustilizing the FSharp.Data CSV Type Provider. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing one back-tick here:

```
row.``Petal Width`|])
```

It should be:

```
row.``Petal Width``|])
```

Comment: AH! Now I do feel stupid thank you for the catch, guess I need some sleep :-)

Comment: @user2930378 No problem. If this answer solved your issue, don't forget to accept it. That lets other users know the issue has been resolved, and helps future visitors if they encounter some a similar issue. See also [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) Happy coding.

Comment: @user2930378 And don't forget to upvote all answers that help (or questions that show effort and are answerable)...